# Get redirected to our payment gateway page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, api, payment

I want to make a Payment Gateway on magento 2 and I developed a Model. By this I want to get all values from magento 2 and post it our payment gateway means I want to redirect it please suggest me the code is below

```
namespace Xyz\Abc\Model;
class XyzPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{    
    protected $_code = 'xyzpaymentmethod';

    protected $_isOffline = false;

    public function capture(\Magento\Payment\Model\InfoInterface $payment, $amount)
    {
        echo '<pre>';

        print_r($payment);
        print_r($amount);

        exit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Any Updates  after editing?

Comment: you can study this module.
[uchenic/magento2-module-payment-tmrobokassa](https://github.com/uchenic/magento2-module-payment-tmrobokassa)

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of changes, need to your Payment method class.

1. **Need to redirect to a Magento Custom Page**.
2. **Then From this Custom page  submit a form which will hit payment gateways.**
3. **After Payment done/failure .paygate redirect to you a page**

***For 1st step1, you need do below change***

add

```
   public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('[RouteName]/[Controller]/[Action]');
    }
```

Your model class should be like this:

```
<?php

namespace Xyz\Abc\Model;
/* add by Amit Bera*/
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Payment\Transaction;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
/**
 * Bank Transfer payment method model
 *
 * @method \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\PaymentMethodExtensionInterface getExtensionAttributes()
 */
class XyzPaymentMethod extends \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\AbstractMethod
{
    const PAYMENT_METHOD_XYZ_CODE = 'xyzpaymentmethod';

    /**
     * Payment method code
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = self::PAYMENT_METHOD_XYZ_CODE;

 /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isGateway = false;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canOrder = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canAuthorize = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canCapture = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canCapturePartial = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canRefund = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canRefundInvoicePartial = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canVoid = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canUseInternal = false;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canUseCheckout = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canFetchTransactionInfo = true;

    /**
     * Availability option
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canReviewPayment = true;

    /**
     * Website Payments Pro instance
     *
     * @var \Magento\Paypal\Model\Pro
     */
    /**
     * Get instructions text from config
     *
     * @return string
     */
   /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $_checkoutSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory
     */
    protected $_exception;
     /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;   

   /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param Logger $logger
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
      public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Payment\Helper\Data $paymentData,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Payment\Model\Method\Logger $logger,
        /* add by Amit Bera */
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedExceptionFactory $exception,
         \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
          PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        /* add by Amit Bera */
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $paymentData,
            $scopeConfig,
            $logger,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
            );



        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_exception = $exception;         
      }

    public function getInstructions()
    {
        return trim($this->getConfigData('instructions'));
    }
     public function getCheckoutRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl('[RouteName]/[Controller]/[Action]');
    }


}
```

**Step2**

For create url you need a custom url which is need contoller   file

For this follow inchoo block

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/how-to-create-a-basic-module-in-magento-2/

On this file at execute().. you can get curren  placed order by below code

```
$LastorderObject=$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        if (!$LastorderObject-> getLastRealOrder()->getId()) {
            return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('checkout/cart');
        }
```

then render block class with phtm file .. on phmtl submit form in hidden process
nad redirect to payment gateway

Answer (score 0):

In order to build payment module with redirect you have to use Payment Gateway API presented in the Magento/Payment module. First of all you have to remove usage of `AbsractMethod` class usage due to a fact that this class is deprecated and no longer supported. In the upcoming releases it likely to be removed.

There is [Magento/Payment/Model/Method/Adapter](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.3/app/code/Magento/Payment/Model/Method/Adapter.php) class exist as a new Facade when configuring payment method. With this class you can create custom Builders for different payment requests e.g. Cancel payment, Refund payment, Recurring payment and Initialization of a payment during redirect.

This class however, is a starting point for redirect implementation. Please read my answer in the [Payment gateway with redirects in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146444/payment-gateway-with-redirects-in-magento2/158046#158046) where I explain steps of creating redirect to a payment provider

Please also read about [Payment Gateway Configuration](https://www.maxpronko.com/blog/magento-2-payment-adapter-configuration) to configure `Magento/Payment/Model/Method/Adapter` class via `di.xml` file for your custom payment module.

Hope it helps.