# Magento 2: Observer not redirecting to checkout page

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect, magento-2.1.4

I have below code of observer

```
namespace Custom\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $_urlManager;
    protected $_checkoutSession;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $_redirect;
    protected $_request;
    protected $_response;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_resultFactory;
    protected $_scopeConfig;
    protected $_product;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, \Magento\Framework\App\Response\RedirectInterface $redirect, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart, \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager, \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory, \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $resultFactory
    ) {
        $this->_urlManager = $urlManager;
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->_redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_response = $response;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_resultFactory = $resultFactory;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->_product = $product;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {

       // $this->_redirect->redirect($this->_response, $this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout'));
       // $resultRedirect = $this->_resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
       // $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout'));
       $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout'))->sendResponse();
        // $this->_response->setRedirect($this->_urlManager->getUrl('checkout'));
         $this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(true); // Redirect to Checkout Page
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Have tried with `$this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(true);` & `$this->_checkoutSession->setNoCartRedirect(false);`

Other classes used for my purpose.

Pages loads on Console (Firebug). But not redirecting actually on checkout page.

Comment: try this getUrl('checkout/index/index')

Comment: Which event you are using ?

Comment: Using `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event @KeyurShah

Comment: `getUrl('checkout/index/index')` only @BilalUsean or `$this->`?

Comment: I don't see any fault in your code may be some where else magento hard code like need to mention like route/controller/action -> checkout/index/index that's why I suggest

Answer (score 1):

You need to use code which is following as:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class TestObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url)
    {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $cartUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($cartUrl)->sendResponse();            
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not giving any error in log as well, But it's not redirecting to checkout page

Comment: I used this code in my observer, Tryu with remove cache.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161223/magento-2-same-event-with-multiple-observer-in-different-module-causes-redirect

Comment: @AnkitShah Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope @Dhiren not working

Comment: you have called your observer from another observer?

Comment: Nope. Both observer called on their from individual Module. Only order is defined that whick observer called 1st

Comment: In Fresh Magento 2.1.4 Works fine. Checking what causing issue in mine

Comment: Ok. And if above answer help you, accept it. So it will help other in community as well.